# JavaScript Collision

Tags: javascript

I found a JS collision code here. It is:

```
function isCollide(a, b) {
    return !(
        ((a.y + a.height) < (b.y)) ||
        (a.y > (b.y + b.height)) ||
        ((a.x + a.width) < b.x) ||
        (a.x > (b.x + b.width))
    );
}
```

I would need something easy like this, but I need to know if it collided on left side, right side, top side, or down side.

Do you have a code for this or something, please,

Comment: Have you managed to figure out what this is doing, and further tried to make the changes? If not, then someone providing the 'enhanced' code isn't going to leave you any wiser.

Comment: What attempts have you made to modify the code you found?

Comment: I guess you guys didn't get the memo; programming is the modern alchemy. It's just magic. Gimme the codez!

Answer (score 1):

Just make the code use if statements for each of the above cases and then when one of them is true return a code that relates to what side to collision is located. i.e.

```
function isCollide(a, b) {
if(!((a.y + a.height) < (b.y)))
    return 1;
else if(!(a.y > (b.y + b.height)))
    return 2;
else if(!((a.x + a.width) < b.x))
    return 3;
else if(!(a.x > (b.x + b.width))(
    return 4;
return false;
}
```

Then in the calling code check to see what the function returns